# Downloading the Tower Bridge Defence project for Unity 4.3

Tags: unity-game-engine

The new release of Unity 4.3 includes a 2D game engine.

http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new

The video says that they have created a demo project for people to learn how to use it.

However, when I go to the asset store it just imports all the components in to my current project.

Is there a way to download the full actual project?

So I can see it all working.

Comment: This is a question for the Unity3d forums http://forum.unity3d.com/forum.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is the way to download it. If you don't want it to mess up the current project you're working on, start a new separate project specifically for this demo.

On download you don't have to import it. You can safely cancel that if you're in the middle of another project. It will just be part of your downloaded asset store assets then. You can subsequently import it in a new project. But that is how it works.

Comment: Thanks, but if I do this I still just have all the components in the project ready to add. Nothing is actually added. i.e. if I hit "Play" then the screen is blank. Is there any way to see the completed game?

Comment: Just open the scene named "Level" from the Scenes folder within the project. That is the game level and that you can play.

Comment: I want to mention you need to search the asset store for '2D Platformer'.  In the asset store it is under Complete Projects/Tutorials.  Download it, then find in your assets under Assets/Scenes as the item 'Level'.

Answer (score 0):

It is called now "2d Platformer"

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/2d-platformer-11228

If you want to learn how to make controller with same assets I recommend: https://youtu.be/Cl5oLdo3v3k